# How to add CSS from Library in B2C?

Tags: css, b2c

I have a CSS file from the library on Business Manager and want to add that css file to every page in storefront, what should I do?

Comment: When you say storefront, are you referring to B2B (CloudCraze)? Or something else like Communities?

Comment: storefront of B2C,bro